# Is this function with atomic thread-safe

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic

I am trying to learn how to use atomic :)

```
class foo {
  static std::atomic<uint32_t> count_;
  uint32 increase_and_get() {
    uint32 t = count_++;
    return t;
  }
}
```

Is the function `increase_and_get()` thread-safe?

Comment: The way it's implemented I'd call this `get_and_increase` rather than `increase_and_get`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is safe: the increment is atomic, and the local `t` cannot be altered by concurrent threads. You can further simplify your code to eliminate the temporary variable altogether:

```
uint32 increase_and_get() {
    return count_++;
}
```

Comment: Without atomic an increment of a memory location is not guaranteed to be atomic, no. Even on x86, it's possible that two processors try to increment at once, and without atomic, it may result in the same value from two different calls. (reply to a removed comment!)

Comment: @MatsPetersson that's the whole point of `std::atomic`, isn't it?

Comment: I just edited my comment - note that this was intended as a reply to a comment that apparently got removed.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it would be threadsafe. Assuming of course there are no bugs in the `std::atomic` implementation - but it's not usually hard to get right.

This is exactly what `std::atomic` is meant to do.